# Remove inline style for ajaxtoolkit Combobox -button

Tags: html, css, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxToolkit combobox in my page... I am trying to **change the width of combo-button** . But I couldnot. Because it has inline style by default..

I tried the following code to add style

//Combo css

```
 .ComboClass .ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button
        {
            border-radius: 0px;
            box-shadow: 0px; 
            width     :12px; height:12px;      
        }
```

But border-radius and Box-shadow styles are applying but **Width& height is not applying** ..

Because ComboBox Button got default inline styles.. I cant remove that line styles too..

Please post me some suggestions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works.. Little change on my css. I just added !important property to override the default element (Inline styles)..

```
<style type="text/css">
        .ComboClass .ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button
        {               
            box-shadow: 0px;
            width: 14px !important;
            height: 15px !important;
        }
</style>
```

Now I can change width & height of the combo-button.

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript function to search for and strip the attributes on document ready.
The jquery way is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
document.find(".ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer").removeClass("ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer").addClass("myAwesomeClassWithCoolDimensions");    
});
```

Make sure your css has a myAwesomeClassWithCoolDimensions class.

Comment: That was the idea, then all the styling would be in the css file.

Just read your answer and almost said "DOH!" out loud.

Comment: This one u have told me that gonna update the cssStyle.. But by default i had some inline styles on my combo button . For overriding the styles we need use !important alone enough dude... we doesnt need a jquery in my option....

Comment: Correct. Hence my almost out loud exclamation.